# command not found when trying to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When trying to set up AWS Elastic Beanstack for my Django project following this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

once I get to running

```
eb create django-env
```

I get this error:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
Creating application version archive "app-2f30-181013_230403".
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 1 Error: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: basename: command not found
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: sed: command not found
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 18: .: git-sh-setup: file not found
```

Any ideas what the issue is here? is AWS Elastic Beanstack unusable from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You have a Windows path and program compatibility problem.

The EB CLI works just fine on Windows. I use it almost everyday on many corporate systems for different customers. This assumes that everything is installed and setup correctly.

1) Make sure that you have installed the Windows native version of Git. Install from this location:
[Downlading Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

2) Make sure that the Windows native version of Git is before Mingw in your Windows search path. Otherwise the wrong program will be loaded and then all the Mingw environment and dependencies will mess everything up.

3) Make sure that the latest version of EB CLI is installed (do this last). Follow these steps to repair your current installation. Depending on what you have setup, just installing EB CLI may be enough.

[Install Python, pip, and the EB CLI on Windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html)